# Scope of (const) variable when is not defined as extern or static

Tags: ios, objective-c, static, extern, linkage

I have some constant variables which I want to be global, and some of them should be available only in the file where are defined. So I use extern and static keywords, like this:

```
extern const int kMaxHealth = 100;
static NSString * const kName = @"Name";
```

This is just an example, and those are defined in different files, so this is not a real situation...

But what is the scope of variable when is defined without modifiers, like this:

```
const int kMaxHealth = 100;
```

Is kMaxHealth extern now, or static, or have some other scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has the same scope as a normal variable would without the `const` , but does not allow you to assign a new value to the variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
const int kMaxHealth = 100;
```

`kMaxHealth` is just a global variable. A non-static variable defined at file scope can have external linkage. For example, in any header file you can use it as -

```
extern const int kMaxHealth;
```